# How to prevent CSS animation resetting after each cycle

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Is there a way to prevent CSS animation reset after each cycle is done? I hope it starts from the previous position instead of the initial position.

```css
@keyframes spin{
  0%{
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  50%{
    transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
}

.spinning{
    position: absolute;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.spinning::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:red;
    top:-5px;
    left:20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="" href="">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="spinning"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

as you can see, after each rotation, the red dot resets to the top of the circle, but that is not what I want, I want it to start rotating from top of the circle, then bottom, then top, then bottom, and so on.
I don't speak English well, I hope you get what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot moves back to the original position (0%) because the last `keyframe` was at `180deg`. To make it so that it completes the whole circle, you will have to end at `360deg`. So it is still resetting, but since `360deg` and `0deg` are technically the same position, you will not see this "transition".

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.spinning {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite forwards;
}

.spinning::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  top: -5px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spinning"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for answering. yes I could've made it into a single @keyframes, but that is not what I wanted to do. I was trying to make a loading spinner, there are multiple dots on the circle, only one dot is spinning at a time, when the first dot hits second one, the first one will stop moving, and second one starts rotating, It's kinda like Newton's cradle. I guess I need JS to do this.

Comment: Is this more in the direction that you wanted to accomplish? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/wauLkbxp/34/)

Comment: @omersahban You should include this info inside your posted question, and you certainly don't need any JS, easily achievable with CSS.